# The differential equation $-y''+(1+x)y=\lambda y,x\in (0,1).$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem $$-y''+(1+x)y=\lambda y,x\in (0,1), y(0)=y(1)=0$$ has a non zero solution

$1.$ for all $\lambda <0.$

$2.$ for all $\lambda\in[0,1].$

$3.$ for some $\lambda\in (2,\infty).$

$4.$ for a countable number of $\lambda$'s.

I am thinking it like the ODE $y''+q(x)y=0$ if $q(x)$ is continuous and negative then any non trivial solution of ODE has at most one zero . But the given ODE already has two zeros one at $0$ and one at $1.$ So whenever we choose $\lambda$ so that our $q(x)$ is negative then the above ODE has no non trivial solution corresponding. So according to me $3$rd  and $4$th options are  only correct options as we can write the given ODE as $$y''-(1+x-\lambda)y=0.$$ Please suggest me correct thinking about this question. Thanks a lot.