# $-y''+(1+x)y= \lambda y$ for which value of $\lambda$ the eqn has nonzero solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, power-series, linear-pde

The problem is the following 
$$\begin{cases}-y''+(1+x)y= λy\\  
y(0)=y(1)=0\\ x\in(0,1)\end{cases}$$ *For which value if $\lambda$ the problem has nonzero solutions?*

The answers given are

1. for all $\lambda<0$
2. for all $\lambda\in[0,1]$.
3. for some $\lambda\in(2,\infty)$
4. for a countable number of $\lambda$'s

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there theorems in your course you can use, which might help you? For example something about eigenvalues of linear elliptic operators?

Comment: What about your work?

Comment: Same question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838947/the-differential-equation-y1xy-lambda-y-x-in-0-1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318378/how-to-find-out-which-of-the-following-are-true, similar question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2686316/non-zero-solutions-for-y1xy-ay-0x1-y0-y1-0.

Answer (score 1):

Just a partial answer: Multiply your equation with $y$ and integrate. Then you obtain
$$-\int_0^1 y'' ydx + \int_0^1(1+x)y^2dx = \lambda \int_0^1y^2dx$$
Now use integration by parts on the first integral to get
$$-[y'y]_0^1 + \int_0^1(y')^2dx + \int_0^1(1+x)y^2dx = \lambda \int_0^1y^2dx,$$
which simplifies by the boundary values to
$$\int_0^1(y')^2dx + \int_0^1(1+x)y^2dx = \lambda \int_0^1y^2dx.$$
$x\in[0,1]$ further yields
$$\int_0^1y^2\, dx\leq \lambda \int_0^1 y^2dx,$$
which exclude option 1) and 2). For $\lambda=1$ you need go through the argument again and proceed by contradiction.

Existence can be done in a more general context. Look up Gilbarg/Trudinger's book on elliptic partial differential equations of second order. It should be Theorem 8.37.
This is a reference to the book:
https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540411604